# Event when I remove the cursor from an Input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At the moment I have following JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var suchfeld =  $("#suchfeld");
 if(suchfeld.val()==0){
  suchfeld.val("Suche...");
 }
 suchfeld.click(function(){
  if(suchfeld.val()=="Suche..."){
  suchfeld.val("");
  }
 });
});
```

I want that the if(suchfeld.val()==0){ also excutes when the User click on any other thing outside suchfeld on my site. How can I handle this?

Comment: can you not use the placeholder attribute? there are plenty of polyfills if you need to support older browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `blur` event to track it. This is an event called, whenever the user leaves an element.

```
suchfeld.blur(function() {
    if( suchfeld.val() == 0 ) {
        suchfeld.val("Suche...");
    }
});
```

The opposide is `focus`, not `click`.

```
$(function() {
    var suchfeld = $("#suchfeld");

    // or suchfeld.focus(function() {});
    suchfeld.on("focus", function() {
        if( suchfeld.val() == "Suche..." ) {
            suchfeld.val("");
        }
    });

    // or suchfeld.blur(function() {});
    suchfeld.on("blur", function() {
        if( suchfeld.val() == 0 ) {
            suchfeld.val("Suche...");
        }
    });
});
```

You can chain these too:

```
$(function() {
    $("#suchfeld").focus(function() {
        if( suchfeld.val() == "Suche..." ) {
            suchfeld.val("");
        }
    })
    .blur(function() {
        if( suchfeld.val() == 0 ) {
            suchfeld.val("Suche...");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `suchfeld.blur(function () { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Or by javascript way:

```
<input type="text" id="suchfeld" onblur="iWillCallWhenBlur(this.value)" />
```

and inside `<script>` tag defined your function,

```
function iWillCallWhenBlur(value){
    // your stuff
    // and `value` is the value of text field, when blurred!!
}
```